# Ruby: undefined method `digits' for 3212:Fixnum (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

The code below is meant to take in an integer, square each digit, and return the integer with the squared digits.

However, I kept having this error:

```
`square_digits': undefined method `digits' for 3212:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
    from `
'
```

I don't understand why I have this error as the .digits method is an included method in ruby and I'm using it on an integer, yet it gives me a NoMethodError.

```
def square_digits(digit)

  puts digit
  puts digit.inspect
  puts digit.class

  if digit <= 0
    return 0
  else
    #converts the digit into digits in array
    split_digit = digit.digits
    puts "split digit class and inspect"
    puts split_digit.inspect
    puts split_digit.class

    # multiples each digit by itself
    squared = split_digit.map{ |a| a * a}
    squared.reverse!

    # makes digits into string
    string = squared.join('')

    # converts string into integer
    string.to_i
  end

end
```

Does anyone know what is going on??

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? AFAIK `Integer#digits` came in with Ruby 2.4 (the latest version).

Comment: I'm using the latest on my computer, but the code is being run on another computer. I don't know the version of their ruby. This could be the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you are using older version of Ruby than 2.4.0. If so then this method will not be available. It is added in 2.4.0. See this [link](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-digits)

To add support for you old ruby version you can just add below code before your method definition.

```
class Integer
  def digits(base: 10)
    quotient, remainder = divmod(base)
    quotient == 0 ? [remainder] : [*quotient.digits(base: base), remainder]
  end
end
```

After adding this code snippet you should be able to run your method.

Comment: It would be better to protect that shim with guard code so that you don't redefine it needlessly, or put the method in your own module instead of using the `Integer#digits` slot.